# Spring websocket in existing project- not working

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-websocket

I have an existing project in Spring MVC which works as expected without any issues. Iam able to take view pages via controller.

Now i configure spring websocket into this existing project using below code

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }


    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket").withSockJS();
    }

}
```

Maven dependencies added mentioned below

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.11.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-messaging -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

This is the only thing i have done, after this my app is not working. When i take url-localhost:8080/myapp am not able to see my view. When i comment websocket configuration class everything works fine.

No error in app or server log- Any clue please !?

Comment: Any one has got an clue?