# spring websocket makes whole project returns 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-websocket

I add websocket to my normal springboot project ,both websocket server and my web api works fine in my local computer, But when I put my project to my server, not only the websocket connection url get 404, but also my web api get 404 either.

Here is my code

WebSocketConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketConfig {
    @Bean
    public ServerEndpointExporter serverEndpointExporter() {
        return new ServerEndpointExporter();
    }
}
```

WebSocketServer.java

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/socketServer/{carId}")
@Component
public class WebSocketServer {

    private Session session;
    private static Map<String, Session> sessionPool = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(16);
    private static Map<String, String> sessionIds = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(16);

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session, @PathParam(value = "carId") String carId) {
        this.session = session;
        sessionPool.put(carId, session);
        sessionIds.put(session.getId(), carId);
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose() {
        sessionPool.remove(sessionIds.get(session.getId()));
        sessionIds.remove(session.getId());
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Session session, Throwable exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

    public static void sendMessage(String carId, String message) throws IOException {
        Session session = sessionPool.get(carId);

        if (session != null) {
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
        }
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.driver</groupId>
<artifactId>alipay</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>Alipay</name>
<description>Alipay MiniProgram</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Even i got the same issue - But didnt get any answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47277160/spring-websocket-in-existing-project-not-working

Comment: I solved my question, you can see if my answer is work for you too.

Comment: i will check and update . Thanks for the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my question after few tests

It seems this is the tomcat problem in your server side

Let us use the springboot inner tomcat

> 1.set your project packing type to jar
>
> 2.set your server.port except 80 and 8080 , I set it to 8081
>
> 3.use `mvn clean package -DskipTests` to package your project to jar
>
> 4.upload your jar file to your server except for the tomcat directory
>
> 5.run your code with `java -jar YOURFILENAME.jar`

Here is my pom.xml file after I change my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.driver</groupId>
<artifactId>websocket</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>WebSocket</name>
<description>WebSocket for MiniProgram</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```